# How can we run one time scripts after installation in electron?

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, electron

I need to run python scripts from my Electron app. I have to set up a python virtual env post installation. Something like the following (but hopefully platform agnostic).

```
cd /Applications/z.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar.unpacked
brew reinstall python
brew upgrade python
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install virtualenv
python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your work.

Comment: Also, when you say "post installation" do you mean each time your app runs, or once after the installer is finished. If it's the latter, couldn't you just put a post-install task in your installer bundle? This would be totally unrelated to Electron.

Comment: I have done what's mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41209644/865220, Now I can trigger python script from electron app inside `/Applications/z.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar.unpacked/` but there is neither guarantee of python nor python modules with appropriate version to be present there, that's why I am looking to setup `virtualenv` there post installation. If you can even suggest other means like deploying docker, vagrant etc I am okay to adopt those as well

Comment: only once and that should happen before user tries to open the app for the first time. sorry for inconvenience I ignored these details thinking that mentioning setting up python environment on client makes these obvious.

Answer (score 0):

**Step one:**

The approach I took is to create a a python native app using `py2app` alongside an electron app
But in that too faced few issues as I was using anaconda.
Following this helped `https://github.com/stuarteberg/helloworld`

**Step two:**

**2(a)**

You will encounter pyqt not found error

> ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtGui

then do

1. `conda install pyqt=4`
2. Restart terminal

**2(b)(optional)**

Above repo is in pyqt4, If you need pyqt5:

To install `pyqt5` on Mac first install `macports`(https://guide.macports.org/#installing.macports), then do

```
unset PYTHONPATH
brew install sip --with-python3
brew install pyqt --with-python3
```